# Type.GetType case insensitive - WinRT

Tags: c#, types, windows-runtime, case-insensitive, objectinstantiation

From [microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a87che9d.aspx), `Type.GetType` can be case-insensitive in .NET 4.5. Unfortunately, this is not available in WinRT (Metro/Modern UI/Store apps).

Is there a known workaround ? Because I have to instantiate objects from a protocol which have all the string representations in uppercase.

Example : from "MYOBJECT", I have to instantiate `MyObject`.

I currently use `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MYOBJECT"))`, but due to the case sensitivity, it does'nt work.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you know the assembly you're loading the types from? If so, you could just create a case-insensitive `Dictionary<string, Type>` (using `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`) by calling `Assembly.GetTypes()` once. Then you don't need to use `Type.GetType()` at all - just consult the dictionary:

```
// You'd probably do this once and cache it, of course...
var typeMap = someAssembly.GetTypes()
                          .ToDictionary(t => t.FullName, t => t,
                                        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

...

Type type;
if (typeMap.TryGetValue(name, out type))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    // Type not found
}
```

EDIT: Having seen that these are all in the same namespace, you can easily filter that :

```
var typeMap = someAssembly.GetTypes()
                          .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Foo.Bar")
                          .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t,
                                        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: @NicolasVoron: Why would it be painful? Just how many types are there, and how many are you fetching? (I was assuming you were fetching many different types by name.)

Comment: Hmmm... Totally misunderstood your answer. Sorry about that. This is a very good solution. Your edit perfectly fits to my needs ;) Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`GetTypes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a87che9d.aspx) method, to fetch all possible types in the assembly where your type is in, after that check which type uppercase equals to your type upper case then use it in `GetType` method.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you actual class name is `Car` and your query string is `CAR`. As these are different in terms of case sensitivity, the Type.GetType() will return null. 
To resolve this first of all filter all the classes from the namespace of `Car`(Assume that the  namespace is `Vehicle`).

```
var varClasses = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                 where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "Vehicles"
                 select t;
```

Convert to a `List`

```
List<Type> lstClasses = varClasses.ToList();
```

Declare a variable to get the actual name of the class and use a loop to compare string without case-sensitivity.

```
string strActualName = "";
foreach (Type t in lstClasses )
{
     if (t.Name.ToLower() == "CAR".ToLower())
     {
           strActualName = t.Name;
           break;
     }
}
```

Now with the new string, use the Type.GetType()

```
Type t1 = Type.GetType("Vehicles." + strActualName);
```